# Magento Product Stock status changes automatically

Tags: magento2, stock

We are facing an issue with Magento 2.4. We are using MSI and we have 3 warehouses. All products have been assigned 3 warehouses and we manage stock using MSI. A product can be available in one warehouse and can't be available in another, The issue is when we get the product out of stock one day it gets automatically in stock after 1 or 2 days, and its random behavior is not with specific products or warehouse.
Initially, we thought maybe it's done by someone in the team if they worked on the same product so we have set up an alert whenever product gets changed by admin we get notification on Email. But the strange thing is without any alert still status gets changed.

I have used this event `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after`   to trigger an alert whenever a product gets changed and it's working as well we have tested it.

Although we have restricted import functionality for other users, we think the product may be changed through CSV or API although we have restricted but maybe it can be done from any user.

Can anyone please help if someone faced a similar issue or any model function which always triggers whenever product stock status gets changed from any action like API or from CSV or from Admin Edit or even frontend ??

Comment: change event to catalog_product_save_after

Comment: already did but strange thing is with this event changes are not showing it always shows previous values on stock not current

Comment: are you creating credit memo in site?/ it will add stock back to product

Comment: No we don't create credit memos as well..

Comment: Have those products been bought before?

Comment: yes we actually found these products on order like someone ordered and then we get know this products was changed to in stock and we cancel orders